# which variable controls separation of entries in entry set

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

using `\defbibentryset` and `block=nbpar` I would like to replace the default semicolon by a new line to separate entries in the entry sets. Which `biblatex` variable controls it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redefine `\entrysetpunct` (which is not mentioned in the manual -- the definition is located in `biblatex.def`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[block=nbpar]{biblatex}

% Original definition
% \newcommand*{\entrysetpunct}{\addsemicolon\space}

% Changed definition
\renewcommand*{\entrysetpunct}{\par\vspace{\bibitemsep}}

\defbibentryset{myset}{A01,B02}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{myset,C03}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll add `\entrysetpunct` to the manual for 2.6.

Comment: @PLK: Do you notice my new issue at Github?

Comment: I did ... looking at it.

Comment: Here the issue: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/104

Comment: I have a problem with this approach. My bibliography style has `\newblockpunct` redefeined as `\renewcommand*{\newblockpunct}{---}`. This results in an extra dash as the separator between the entries. How can I get rid of it?